# × Component tns-core-modules is not installed. × Component tns-android is not installed. × Component tns-ios is not installed

Tags: android, nativescript, tns

What am I missing, I have completed all the steps asked in the installation guide of **nativescript** running tns doctor gives me the following output...

```
C:\abc\xyz>tns doctor
√ Getting environment information

√ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
√ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
√ The Android SDK is installed.
√ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
√ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
√ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
√ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
No issues were detected.
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 4.0.2 version and is up to date.
× Component tns-core-modules is not installed.
× Component tns-android is not installed.
× Component tns-ios is not installed.
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this - `tns platform add android`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to checked your `package.json`? Or try to execute `npm i`? or `tns install`?

Comment: Yeah, creating a project took care of the tns-core-modules, but the tns-android and tns-ios is still crossed even after being in the package,json file.

Comment: Did you try `tns platform install android/ios`? and checked if `platform` folder exists in your app root directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think two points about it:

1. Seems like you don't followed the `NativeScript quick setup` to installed it because it could be installed all together. https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup
2. You should check inside your `package.json` if this modules exists:

`× Component tns-core-modules is not installed.
× Component tns-android is not installed.
× Component tns-ios is not installed.`

You also check doing this: `npm ls <module-name>`, where `<module-name>` is the module to check it.

Let me know if it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install manually using npm i

```
npm i @nativescript/core
npm i -D @nativescript/android @nativescript/ios
```