# You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android Support Repository installed on your system

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm facing an issue. In **sidekick** when I try to run on my android device, this is result:

[image: screenshot of sidekick]

I verify variable `ANDROID_HOME` and it points to the good path. In cmd in my project I have tried `tns doctor`and the result is:

[image: Screenshot of tns doctor in my project folder]
The
**Also android SDK ScreenShot in android Studio:**[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrLop.png),[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctCEW.png),[third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSea2.png),[fourth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXzh4.png).

This is my config:

- npm 6.4.1
- Window 10 Entreprise

Please help me!

Comment: Would you mind showing us the list of API levels, Tools & Support libs you have installed, probably you may take a screenshot from Android Studio - SDK Manager.

Comment: Did you try restart of your machine after installing sidekick, may be the environment variables are not set and CLI not installed propertly. Some previous issues here - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5690 and previous stackoverflow issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520734/%C3%97-component-tns-core-modules-is-not-installed-%C3%97-component-tns-android-is-not-in

Comment: @manoj how can i add pictures? I don't know how to do.

Comment: @Baskar thanks... let me try and i will tell you.

Comment: @Manoj i edit the question. thanks

Comment: As @Baskar mentioned already, did you get a chance to verify the environment variables are in place by running the commands in terminal (`android` / `adb`).

Comment: @Manoj yes both work. have you seen other pictures of android sdk in android studio?

Comment: Yes, I checked the screenshots. Looks like you are using the very old SDK (Lollipop). Google itself started restricting it to Oreo, try installing API level 26.

Comment: @Manoj I tried, but I still have the same mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using nativescript 4.2.0 and i tried to upgrade to the version 5.0.0 and this is work for me.  the command that i used is : `npm install nativescript@next -g`. and when i run : `tns run android --bundle` everything work fine.

Answer (score 1):

On your screenshots I don't see any SDK platform installed for API level higher than 22. Please install higher level APIs and try again. You need SDK platforms, only SDK tools are not enough.

[image: SDK platform]